# Dynamically add imageViews in a circular layout in Android

Tags: android

I want to add imageViews dynamically in a circle like a round plate.
Android dose not provide a circular layout so please help me to create a circular layout..
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check this out , this link shows how to make view in circular shape... just imlement your image view in it ...

http://developer.samsung.com/android/samples-4

or you can do this by xml :

```
<LinearLayout orientation=vertical for whole screen>
    <LinearLayout weight=1 gravity=center> <!--- Top --->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout weight=1 orientation=horizontal> <!-- middle -->
        <LinearLayout weight=1 gravity=left/>
        <LinearLayout weight=1 gravity=right/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout weight=1> <!-- botton -->
        <LinearLayout weight=1 gravity=center/>
        <LinearLayout weight=1 gravity=center/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a special layout for this.You can use a Relative Layout or a Frame Layout.

Just add the views dynamically in the normal way but position them using margin, padding etc so that they look like a circle.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I can see that you need a circular layout on Android to arrange your images. I think this [library](https://github.com/xresco/CircularLayout) will help you doing this. this library gives you the ability to add item, rotate them with animation. Check it out!

Comment: Thanks xresco helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use HorizontalScrollView.